# Should django model manager know about model class?

Tags: django, model

Is this a bad practise that a model manager know about the model class? It seems like a circular reference.

eg.

```
from .models import Entry

class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def sync(data):
        try:
          self.get(slug=slug)
        except Entry.DoesNotExist:
          pass
```

If it is not a bad practise then how do I get the model class within a manager without using the import statement?

I would assume something like:

```
class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def sync(data):
        try:
          self.get(slug=slug)
        except self.get_model().DoesNotExist:
          pass
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just been through the django code and there is class variable in the manager:

```
self.model
```